# How to use the sql function CONCAT with a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies, concatenation

**SCROLL DOWN TO HELP ME, THE PROBLEM IS EXPLAINED.**

**PROBLEM ALMOST SOLVE !**

I am trying to perform an automatic login script with cookies and I came across a very interesting tutorial: http://blog.monstruosor.com/2013/05/18/php-auto-connexion-par-cookie/

Here is the code he proposes :

```
function autologin() {
$key = $_COOKIE['autologin'];

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('SEL1-df546', `name`, `id`, 'SEL2-sd55fd', `last_connection`, $ip))=$key";
$infos = $users->exec($query);

if(!is_array($infos) || empty($infos)) {
    // Mauvais cookie !
    return false;
}

$_SESSION['user'] = $infos; // Mise en SESSION
return true;
```

The main line that interests me is this one:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('SEL1-df546', `name`, `id`, 'SEL2-sd55fd', `last_connection`, $ip))=$key";
$infos = $users->exec($query);
```

However, it is not secure. I want to know how to use an application prepared on this line.
I tried this but it does not work:

```
    $req = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`, ip = :ip)) = :key");
    $req->execute(array(
        'ip' => htmlspecialchars($ip),
        'key' => htmlspecialchars($key)));
```

The  `$this->_db` is from my class and is well written don't worry. The problem comes from here :

```
$req = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`, ip = :ip)) = :key");
```

Hope someone has a solution.

---

Here's more information :

my index.php page contains :

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key = $_COOKIE['auto_login'];
$mg->autoLogin($ip, $key);
```

and my autoLogin method from my class :

```
    public function autoLogin($ip, $key)
{
    $req = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`, :ip)) = :key");
    $req->execute(array(
        'ip' => htmlspecialchars($ip),
        'key' => htmlspecialchars($key)));
    $donnee = $req->fetch();    
    $req->closeCursor();
    if(!is_array($donnee) || empty($donnee)) 
    {
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $donnee;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you still need **more information, just ask me**, I'll update my question again !

---

**HERE'S THE LAST PROBLEM**

**Thanks to pala_ who almost resolve it**

I know where the problem is. 
In my database, the IP stored of the member I'm trying to log in is " ::1 ". But when I do " echo $ip; " which is generated here : "$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ", I have " 127.0.0.1 " ! It's not the same IP when I do my verification so the problem is probably here ! Any idea how to fix this ?

The problem is here because if I do " $ip = '::1'; ", it's WORKING. Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$req = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`, :ip)) = :key");
```

The error is here: `ip = :ip` just needs to be `:ip` and also here `CONCAT(HASH1-1dg9sf'` needs to be `CONCAT('HASH1-1dg9sf'`

Here is some complete, tested (and working) code. Uses PDO.

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`, :ip)) = :key");
        $ip = '10.0.0.1';
        $key = 'HASH1-1dg9sf2himHASH2-dt5w1qalso10.0.0.1';
        $key = sha1($key);
        $res = $stmt->execute(array('ip' => $ip, 'key' => $key));
        print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

And has the following output:
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => him
            [last_name] => also
            [ip] => 10.0.0.1
        )

)
```

which is retrieved from the following row from my test database:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('HASH1-1dg9sf', `id`, `first_name`, 'HASH2-dt5w1q', `last_name`,'10.0.0.1'));
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id   | first_name | last_name | ip        |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | me         | last      | 127.0.0.1 |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I will update my question to bring more detail

Comment: hm. you go from using `users` table to `members` table. which is it?

Comment: The members one, the users is from the tutoriel in the website I found, but good idea

Comment: Don't worry, it's the first time I use this sql function and I'm lost a bit too, we are here for this:)

Comment: if its still not working the other question would be how you are generating the $key value

Comment: @SamirAkeb i've just thrown up some samples that i've tested. if that's still not working for you then the problem is going to be with how `$_COOKIE['auto_login']` is generated

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the code and it's still working. I think I know where the problem is. In my database, the IP stored of the member I'm trying to log in is " ::1 ". But when I do " echo $ip; " which is generated here : "$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ", I have " 127.0.0.1 " ! It's not the same IP when I do my verification so the problem is probably here ! Any idea how to fix this ?  **EDIT** : The problem is here because if I do " $ip = '::1'; ", it's WORKING. Any idea??

Comment: two choices, either access the page via `http://[::1]` instead of `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`, or update the values in the database to be `127.0.0.1` instead of `::1`

Comment: Ok there's not a way to fix this thing ? Because for my future tests, I don't want to always change the IP which is crucial. Is there a way to change it officially ?

Comment: You are checking an ip, and then logging in from a different ip. To fix it, you log in via the same ip as such: `http://[::1]`, or you update the record to be from the ip you are going to log in from. These are your choices if you're going to use ip as part of the security. `[::1]` and `127.0.0.1` will point to the exact same machine. the former is ipv6 and the latter is ipv4. that's where your problem is. Your script is actually working fine - since the purpose seems to be to auto login people when they access from the same IP address again, and you are testing from a different one, it fails.